# Deploying Resque made Rake & Ruby sucking 100% of server's CPU

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, capistrano, resque

After deploying using Resque, CPU consumption increase 100% from Rake & Ruby without even doing anything, no requests, no background jobs or anything.

for deployment I just use `require 'capistrano-resque'` after that I run `after 'deploy:restart', 'resque:restart'`

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'resque', :require => 'resque/server'
gem 'resque_mailer'
```

**lib/tasks/resque.rake**

```
require 'resque/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] ||= '*'
end
```

**config/initializers/resque.rb**

```
rails_root = Rails.root || File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../..'
rails_env = Rails.env || 'development'

resque_config = YAML.load_file(rails_root.to_s + '/config/resque.yml')
Resque.redis = resque_config[rails_env]
```

**config/resque.yml**

```
development: localhost:6379
production: MY_DOMAIN:6379
```

My server is an ubuntu with 1 CPU & 1 GB RAM, would that be the problem, or there is something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: how much worker did u started with resque Also ensure that  whether the old worker still not working

Comment: I just have 1 worker + when I just noticed that when I use `VVERBOSE=1 QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work` It doesn't take that much processing. Maybe its in the Capistrano configuration.